# Share Desktop via Web Browser

Tags: remote-desktop

I need to share my Desktop with users that don't use Linux. I'm looking for a tool where users can hit a URL in their browser and view my desktop, like join.me for Windows.

I tried running join.me via Wine, but I get nothing but a black screen.

Answer (score 17):

[whereby.com](https://whereby.com/) (formerly appear.in) works well for me so far.  It's like join.me in the old days, where it used to work on Linux in the browser, and you didn't even need an account.

Comment: Lately, I can only get it to work with Chrome though, not Chromium.

Comment: It works in Firefox. There was a bug in Firefox 45 that caused it to crash; it works well in 53, but I had to install it from mozilla.org (Debian Jessie only has Firefox ESR 45)

Comment: It works well, but allows only 8 viewers (in the free version) or 12 viewers (in the paid version).

Comment: It can only share all three monitors or a single window... why not one monitor? Also, couldn't find my microphone (I use jack... it needs to open a jack client so I can connect it). Then, when I tried it anyway with just a single window, the other computer was just saying "Connecting..." forever. Ugh. Horrible experience.

Comment: The link is now broken, the app name changed to https://whereby.com/

Answer (score 13):

Have you looked at [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/)?

No client software is necessary and it serves direct to a web browser.

Comment: The installation manual is depressingly long: http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/installing-guacamole.html  Isn't there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 9):

In [Google hangout](https://plus.google.com/hangouts), you can also share your desktop to others.

Comment: I could share the screen, but no keyboard controll.

Comment: You can hangout with at most 10 people (including yourself): https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/yM1kI5-B1Jo

Answer (score 5):

The [Jitsi video bridge](http://meet.jit.si) is not only a video chat but also supports screen sharing. You also get a text chat and an etherpad.

There is only one downside: 
[Chome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) or [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) is required at the moment because the other browsers lack some features Jitsi is making use of. But this is just a matter of time.

Comment: Looks good. It's open-source and they claim to have no limit on the number of users. I have to check it

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) will probably fit the bill for you.

Pros: It will work.
Cons: Requires Google account, etc.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Problem is that I can't have users asking them to install additional software or forcing them to use Google Chrome, etc.

Comment: I suppose it will work on Chromium too.

Comment: Apparently this allows you to share your computer with a single person.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search gave me this:

It doesn't require your users to install additional software.

VNC

The other option is to use remote desktop over VNC. While VNC is not as feature rich as TeamViewer or LogMeIn, it is readily available on Ubuntu. All you need is an IP address and optionally a password to be able to connect to a computer via VNC.
In Ubuntu you need to enable remote desktop connection. Open System > Preferences > Remote Desktop and place a check against “Allow other users to view your desktop“. Optionally you may also specify a password that would be required to access the computer remotely via VNC.

Source: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-logmein-alternatives-ubuntu/

I hope this helps.

Alternatively you can use xrdp. it uses windows 7 build in remote desktop tool to allow users to connect with you

To install it run the command

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Open Remote Desktop Connection in Windows 7.(click Start button,then search “remote” in search box)

Input the host name or IP address of your Ubuntu machine, then click Connect.

Input your user name and password of Ubuntu, then click Ok to connect.

When you're done simply run the command

```
sudo service xrdp stop
```

to stop sharing your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used VNC for several years and it's ok. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the question, I need a tool where clients use their browser for viewing. Reason: clients use windows and OSX, none of them use Linux.

Comment: your clients can install VNC on windows. On Mac you already have a VNC client which you can run from safari with a URL like: vnc://192.168.0.100
The slightly difficult thing is to provide them with your public IP address, and have it forwarded from your router to your desktop.

Comment: Doesn't VNC require port forwarding on the router, if the VNC server is behind a DHCP router?

Comment: True, but that is explained at length in the installation instructions of VNC. `https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/ae1017368.html#Rae94827`

Answer (score 2):

[Deadsimplescreensharing.com](http://deadsimplescreensharing.com/) is an easy to use and free solution that works with chrome. You can share your screen with Mac, Windows, Linux anything with a browser.

Users can hit a URL and see your shared screen.

Comment: Their free plan allows up to 10 participants and 40 minutes. They have paid plans that allow 30 or 150 participants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FCC freeconferencecall.com or startmeeting.com
both support linux now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: I can't see the issues here. He's given links to two programs which solve the problem. It's not a link only answer, and asking someone to add a tutorial in a software recommendation seems harsh.

Comment: It *is* a link only answer, with a few words of padding.

Comment: I did not find in freeconferencecall.com any mention of desktop sharing.