# How to share screen/window with a remote user?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen, remote, voip

I would like to share my screen or only a window with a remote user, something like Skype screen shearing. Is there any tool in Ubuntu that I can use to easily do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Desktop via Web Browser](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335158/share-desktop-via-web-browser). See also  [Remote control and screen sharing for Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/668950/remote-control-and-screen-sharing-for-ubuntu) at superuser.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TeamViewer for this. To install it go to: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

Then install it using the following sequence of commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_9x/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If using Ubuntu 64bit then download teamviewer_linux_x64.deb and follow the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

One very convenient and free solution is to install the TightVNC (www.tightvnc.com) server on the desktop you want to control.

Teamviewer isnt free if you use it a lot.