# A "teacher" software to broadcast my screen to the students' computers

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

I am teaching a course in a computer-class. The teacher's computer has a Windows OS and a software called "Teacher". It allows the teacher to take control over the students' computers, broadcast my desktop to them, etc.

I want to do the same with my Ubuntu laptop. Is there any software that I can install, that will allow me to act like the "Teacher" software?

I found some programs that offer "classroom control for Ubuntu", such as [Classroom Management Software by Mithware](http://www.mythware.com/classroom-management-software-for-linux) or [ControlAula](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/controlaula/), but they require me to install some software on the students' computers, which I cannot do. I am looking for a software with which I can connect to the existing students' computers.

**EDIT:** since it is not possible to control existing computers without installing a new software on them, is there a software that lets me to at least broadcast my screen to the students' screens? I found some websites that do it, like [appear.in](https://appear.in/) and [screenleap](https://www.screenleap.com/), but they are limited to 8 viewers, while I have about 40...

Comment: Splashtop offers this too but I guess you will always have to install something on the students computer because otherwise the door for hackers would be wide open if there would be such a tool you search fir

Comment: If you can control a remote computer without installing anything upon it...that would indeed be a staggeringly gaping security hole. You can broadcast (several applications do that) without client software, but you cannot control.

Comment: @user535733 actually, broadcasting my screen is the most important thing that I need. How can I do this?

Comment: For merely broadcasting your desktop, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/335158/share-desktop-via-web-browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Veyon](http://veyon.io) is exactly that. Veyon is the successor of [iTALC](http://italc.sourceforge.net)

With it one can lock computers, plus remotely reboot or even shut-off machines. A good thing about it is that it is free with its source-code freely available for subsequent change to meet each user’s need. And, apart from Linux, it can also support Windows machines.

**Features**

It has been designed for usage in school. Therefore it offers a lot of possibilities to teachers, such as

see what’s going on in computer-labs by using overview mode and make snapshots

remote control computers to support and help other people

**show a demo (either in fullscreen or in a window) – the teacher’s screen is shown on all student’s computers in realtime**

lock workstations for moving undivided attention to teacher

send text messages to students

powering on/off and rebooting computers per remote

remote logon and logoff and remote execution of arbitrary commands/scripts

home schooling – its network-technology is not restricted to a subnet and therefore students at home can join lessons via VPN-connections just by installing it's client