# Access to ubuntu based server by web browser with GUI

Tags: networking, server

I am thinking about building home server based on Ubuntu (I don't have much experience in Unix systems). I would like to use it because I want to have trustworthy system for my use and keep my private data safely on other disks (zfs pool). 
My question is can I install f.ex Ubuntu Server Edition and install GUI to it (Budgie, etc) or some webGUI. After that have access to this server remotely from other home pc by web browser and have normal graphical interface in it ( to have "ubuntu desktop inside browser") Is it possible or only option is f.ex remote web access by Cockpit and remote desktop acces by installing VNC Server and connecting by Viewer? I am asking because I will have server placed in home server room without monitor and I would like to have acces to it and use it like normal computer (also away from home by service like dyndns or simillar).

Comment: Remote access = Lag. Be prepared for that frustration. Redrawing the screen many times each second can consume a lot of network bandwidth so make sure your home network and ISP connection can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant sharing the desktop (which will enable you to access remotely) 
this post has interesting suggestions 
[Share Desktop via Web Browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335158/share-desktop-via-web-browser)

Comment: Thanks. I think that stuff like Guacamole will be the best for me